# Trigger sql server

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Buenas noches para todos, en este momento quisiera pedir su ayuda pues tengo un problema con un trigger lo que sucede es que necesito validar que si uno de los valores que se va a insertar el l tabla es diferente me consulte unos datos de otra tabla y posteriormente insertarlos, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
 CREATE  TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_Tag64]
 on [dbo].[Tag64]
 INSTEAD OF INSERT
 as

 DECLARE @LVAL float
 DECLARE @LCARGA int
 DECLARE @LMEZCLA float
 DECLARE @LAGUA float
 DECLARE @LLIPO float
 DECLARE @LHIDRO float
 DECLARE @LPRODUCTO VARCHAR
 DECLARE @LFECHA DATETIME


 begin 
  set nocount on;

  with temp as (
  select row_number() over (order by fecha) as rownum, fecha, tag,valor
  from Tag64 
 )
 SELECT  @LVAL=  valor, @LFECHA=fecha from temp where rownum = @@ROWCOUNT;
 IF @LVAL<> (SELECT Valor from inserted) 
    SELECT @LMEZCLA= val from FloatTable where DateAndTime= @LFECHA and TagIndex=56
    SELECT @LAGUA= val from FloatTable where DateAndTime= @LFECHA and TagIndex=57
    SELECT @LLIPO= val from FloatTable where DateAndTime= @LFECHA and TagIndex=58
    SELECT @LHIDRO= val from FloatTable where DateAndTime= @LFECHA and TagIndex=59
    SELECT @LPRODUCTO= val from StringTable where DateAndTime= @LFECHA and TagIndex=66
    SELECT @LCARGA = val from  FloatTable where DateAndTime= @LFECHA and TagIndex=64
    INSERT Consolidado VALUES(@LPRODUCTO,@LCARGA,@LMEZCLA,@LAGUA,@LLIPO,@LHIDRO,@LFECHA)
 END
```

Pero la verdad no funciona y no se como depurarlo, agradezco su amable colaboracion.

Comment: Cuando dices 'no funciona', a qué te refieres?

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pues que al hacer un insert no inserta

Comment: En el `SELECT` del CTE tienes `rownum = @@ROWCOUNT`. Para qué es? Seleccionas el valor y la fecha donde el número del row sea igual a `rowcount`? Si es para saber si ya existe el valor, por qué no hacer un `select  @lval = valor from Tag64 where Tag64.valor = inserted.valor`?

Comment: El trigger no está correctamente planteado, porque la sentencia de inserción de la tabla `Tag64` no tiene porque tener una sola fila. Por tanto, no puedes almacenar los valores en variables. O utilizas un cursor (no recomendado), o se plantea como una lógica de conjuntos. Además estás usando un trigger instead of y no estas insertando nada en la tabla origen del mismo (al menos no se muestra). Deberías de exponer un ejemplo mínimo de lo que intentas, para recibir una ayuda adecuada. Definición de tablas. Valores actuales. Ejemplo de insert. Resultados esperados.

Comment: Gracias voy a colocar el ejemplo

Comment: En el SELECT del CTE tienes rownum = @@ROWCOUNT. Para qué es? Seleccionas el valor y la fecha donde el número del row sea igual a rowcount? Si es para saber si ya existe el valor, por qué no hacer un select @lval = valor from Tag64 where Tag64.valor = inserted.valores para traer el último registro para compara si el val es igual

Comment: Es muy extraño que se haga un trigger de insert que cambie completamente el insert a una tabla por un insert a otra tabla basándose en los valores de otras 2 tablas. Algo está muy mal con la lógica y el diseño de este sistema.